# How do I name Ajax form fields to be recognized by CakePHP?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cakephp

I want to submit a form via Ajax Javascript to a CakePHP function.

CakePHP actions collect all form fields in `$this->data`. I want to convert my HTML form fields to the acceptable format i.e `$this->data(array)`.

How to do this in Javascript? I'm using jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

There is only one way to POST data, so the conversion must be done by cakephp.

Therefore however you submit a form, as long as it goes to the controller it should be automatically converted to `$this->data`.

Comment: I don't think this is necessarily the case.  You need to POST the data with the variable name starting as data.  So, <input name="data[something]" > will end up in $data['something'].  I may be wrong, but I don't think <input name="something"> will end up in Controller::data.